# How to keep the app secret a secret?

Tags: java, heroku, playframework

Every new Play app gets a new application secret generated into its config file.

`application.secret=asdfadsfdasf`

I'm developing an open source app that will be deployed on Heroku. How can I keep the app secret a secret (e.g. no commit it into source control)?

Where exactly is the app secret used? Perhaps for my limited purposes I don't really have to keep it a secret?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can externalize the secret as an environment variable.

In `conf/application.conf` Simply replace

```
application.secret=abc123...
```

with

```
application.secret=${APP_SECRET}
```

and then set this config var in Heroku with:

```
$ heroku config:add APP_SECRET=abc123...
```

Now you can manage secrets on a per-app basis and avoid checking them into version control.

Comment: and if you aren't going to use heroku to deploy? is there an option to use something like jasypt

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that secret is important, but you can generate new ones for production vs development.  So for development you could check it into SVN then generate a different one for production.

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.0/production

Comment: But my application.conf in SVN (well, git) will be deployed to production. Rephrasing, I want to keep my application.conf under source control. My production deployment will be just a `git push` to Heroku. So, should I run a post-deployment script to change the app key? But ... is this script stored under source control? What are some practical solutions when deploying to Heroku?

Comment: I suppose I was advocating not simply using git push, but you'd need a  script that generates a new key before pushing to production so no it wouldn't be checked into source control.  The question I'm not sure about is if you regenerated that key every time you pushed will that create a problem?  If not it might not be all that important to store the secret in production.

Comment: I don't think changing the app key is a good idea. If you sign on something (e.g. Hash a user password), you need to be able to repeat this exact signature, and I believe this does (should) use the app secret.