# How should I handle secret values in a project in source control?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, version-control

My question is essentially the same as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686394/how-to-keep-the-app-secret-a-secret) but for a Windows Store App, c# and Visual Studio. I want to have an easy way to keep secret values in the project, in a file that can be ignored in (not checked in to) source control. How should I structure my project to store the app secret in a way that makes building/source control easy?

My first idea was to store it in an XML file (not checked in), and load it at runtime, but this leaves it available to the user who installs it, so it should be done at build time. How can I store a couple secret values and have visual studio replace them in my code when my project is built?

Comment: I would never put secrets in source control -- manually add them when a new user comes on to the project.

Comment: It's not clear to me why the user who "installs it" has access to the XML file that is not in source control. Is it bundled in your installer? If so, take it out and make it a run-time dependency.

Comment: @PeterRitchie That's exactly what I'm saying. My question means how can I make project build process easy *without* having that value in source control. I.e, "check out the project, then do x with your app secret". I edited for clarity.

Comment: @Kohanz if the value is stored in an xml file, for example, and it's copied as a content file, and read at run-time, then a user who installs the app would have access to that file/value, just like any image assets included in the package.

Comment: @roiuser Right, so I'm suggesting that you don't include that XML file as content and just read it from a pre-determined location. You should probably refactor it such that the XML file excluded from the build contains ONLY the secret fields that you do not want to share (e.g. passwords)

Comment: @Kohanz yes, and my question is where/when is that xml file read? pre-build event? Environment variable? Do I need a batch file? If so, how do I replace text in a source file from XML in the batch file?

Comment: How about build a one-time crypto dll? save encrypted values in xml files and obtain them back using decrypt method of that crypto dll. Every developer will have the DLL and the encrypted data.

Comment: @roviuser: we used to run a NAnt job to do stuff like this. You'd put the NAnt job into a script which gets called in the post-build event. NAnt is good not just for building, but also for pulling from source control & updating files.

Answer (score 0):

In my company we decide to you following solution. In config file we link sections with "secret" values in external configs.
External configs are on source control. First it wasn't but after a problem when our build server lost a disk we decide it it safer to store it on a place which has backup. The folder in source control (can be also on file server) is really restricted to read and write to only people who needs this. Build process checkouts "project" folder plus "configuration" folder and do build. After build "configuration" folder is deleted. Access to build server is also restricted.

Comment: I'm really looking for more of a technical solution within visual studio of how to store/replace these values. I'm not worried about backing up or checking in the app secret anywhere.

Comment: So store copy config file somewhere where almost nobody has access and on build server checkout project and this config file. You can also use a tool like SnowCheetach and keep only transfarmations in "safe" place. More about tool here:  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SlowCheetahWebconfigTransformationSyntaxNowGeneralizedForAnyXMLConfigurationFile.aspx

Comment: This isn't helpful. I never mentioned a build server, and that still doesn't tell me anything about how or when to read that file. My question is *technical* about reading and using the values, not *semantic* about securing it.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to store the secrets in source control, but store them in an encrypted form. In your development or build environments, use a environment variable to store the key, and decrypt on the fly. That way you get the benefits of source control while keeping your info safe.

It is possible to do this even if you are using app.config or web.config, you just need to modify the configuration from code at startup.

Erick

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**
If you put a secret in an untrusted area (e.g. public source control), it is vulnerable. Even if it's encrypted, with enough diligence it can be retrieved.

The only way to really keep it out of reach is to have an external service that interacts with the 3rd party API. That has its own trade-offs (e.g. user authentication as you mentioned in comments). Especially if your developers need to utilize the 3rd party API when testing, I see no other alternative that will limit the secret's exposure.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the app itself. It's a secret for authenticating against a third party API. I never said it was for the app's configuration.

Comment: The Live Connect integration is 3rd party integration, but it is setup at the Windows Store level instead of the app level. The sub-optimal work-around is to have an intermediate service that answers requests from your app and forwards them to the 3rd party API with the secret. Depending on who controls server security, the server-side secret could be in a config file on the server, and nowhere else.

Comment: What you're suggesting is adding an extra server to prevent an API secret? I would still have to authenticate the user somehow, but now I've got an extra hop. That seems superfluous and doesn't provide anything better than having the value encrypted. This is besides the fact that this is related to protecting the key from the end user, instead of my question, which relates to protecting the key from source control/other developers.

Comment: External service protects against discovery from both user and developer. If you put it out there in source, encrypted or not, it is vulnerable. Are you just trying to prevent public source control surfers from getting it?

Comment: Also note if you store it encrypted in source, I assume you still have to decrypt it before sending it to the 3rd party API. So now the problem has shifted to securing the decryption key instead of the secret.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class file in your project that has slots for all of your secret values, and holds dummy/test values for all of them. Check that into source control with the rest of your project, so that anybody building it without access to the secrets will get some sort of test version.

Then, create a copy of that class file with the real secret values, and put it somewhere outside of source control. Write a batch script in the pre-build event that looks for this class file, and if found, replaces the dummy file that is included in the project with it.

This way, your project can still be in source control and anybody can check it out, build it, and run it in the test mode. Your secret file/values are stored on your build server only, so only when you build the project there will it have the real values.

Do remember to back up your secrets file somewhere. And also remember that .NET code can be decompiled easily, so your secrets may not be as secret as you hope them to be - any user with a .NET reflector can see all of the code in your release assembly, including your secret class.